# "Week-Year" string to a meaningful date or numeric format that can be plotted

Tags: r

I have a set of data that includes date that are in the "week-year" format. Therefore, "30-2010" represents the 30th week in 2010. I'm trying to plot the data, but need to adjust the date values to something in a date format or as a numeric value so that ggplot2 will use it as the labels on my x axis. Any ideas on how this can be done?

```
dte = "30-2010"
```

Comment: Perhaps `as.Date(paste0(dte, "-01"), "%g-%Y-%d")`

Answer (score 0):

Check out `?week` in the lubridate package. This seems to do what you want:

```
library(lubridate)
str <- "30-2010"
wk <- substr(str, 1, 2)
yr <- substr(str, 4, 7)
dt <- as.Date(paste0(yr, "-01-01"))
week(dt) <- as.numeric(wk)
dt
[1] "2010-07-23"
```